# Gnome Activity Journal stalls

Tags: ubuntu, zeitgeist

I installed gnome-activity-journal, restarted zeitgeist and launched gnome-activity-journal, and the app just loads without ever displaying anything. I tried the latest version from the PPA:

```
ii  zeitgeist                             0.8.2-0ubuntu1~ppa1~natty                  event logging framework
ii  zeitgeist-core                        0.8.2-0ubuntu1~ppa1~natty                  event logging framework - engine
ii  gnome-activity-journal                0.6.0-0ubuntu1~natty1~ppa                             graphical user interface for Zeitgeist
```

But the result is the same:

[image: stalled_activity_journal]

The daemon says:

```
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Found 0 events in 0.000194s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Found 53 events in 0.000753s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Got 0 raw events in 0.000776s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Got 53 events in 0.000109s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in _get_event_from_row in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in _get_subject_from_row in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in apply_get_hooks in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Found 28 events in 0.000766s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Got 0 raw events in 0.000444s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Got 28 events in 0.000113s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in _get_event_from_row in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in _get_subject_from_row in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in apply_get_hooks in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Found 236 events in 0.001218s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Got 0 raw events in 0.003643s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Got 236 events in 0.000178s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in _get_event_from_row in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in _get_subject_from_row in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in apply_get_hooks in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Found 115 events in 0.000892s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Got 0 raw events in 0.001598s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Got 115 events in 0.000118s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in _get_event_from_row in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in _get_subject_from_row in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in apply_get_hooks in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Found 10 events in 0.000587s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Got 0 raw events in 0.000191s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Got 10 events in 0.000102s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in _get_event_from_row in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in _get_subject_from_row in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine]     Where time spent in apply_get_hooks in 0.000000s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Found 0 events in 0.000665s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.fts] Indexing 'file:///home/raphink/Pictures/stalled_activity_journal.png'
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.fts] Indexing 'file:///home/raphink/Pictures/stalled_activity_journal.png'
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.fts] Indexing 'file:///home/raphink/Pictures/stalled_activity_journal.png'
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.engine] Inserted 3 events out of 3 in 0.207549s
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.notify] Checking monitor :1.146/org/gnome/zeitgeist/monitor/1
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.notify] Checking monitor :1.146/org/gnome/zeitgeist/monitor/3
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.notify] Checking monitor :1.146/org/gnome/zeitgeist/monitor/2
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.notify] Checking monitor :1.146/org/gnome/zeitgeist/monitor/5
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.notify] Checking monitor :1.146/org/gnome/zeitgeist/monitor/4
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.notify] Checking monitor :1.146/org/gnome/zeitgeist/monitor/6
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.notify] Notifying :1.146/org/gnome/zeitgeist/monitor/6 about 3 insertions
[DEBUG - zeitgeist.fts] Committing FTS index
[WARNING - zeitgeist.notify] Failed to deliver notification: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Fixed the issue. [This is a screenshot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-activity-journal/+bug/831436/+attachment/2502493/+files/sct.png) Just to mention this might also fall in the category of workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem and the [bug is even logged](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-activity-journal/+bug/831436). One of the developers has even found out the reason and [deciding on what to do](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-activity-journal/+bug/831436/comments/14)

---

The bug has been [fixed in Oneiric](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-activity-journal/+bug/831436) and is [uploaded in the archives](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-activity-journal)

The bug has been [fixed in our official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~zeitgeist/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=natty). Please do an update